# C++ Cli WebClient not working in a dll

Tags: c#, c++, .net, command-line-interface, webclient

I am trying to download a string from a webaddress using WebClient in C++/Cli.
However it fails after the dll is injected into a native process.

This is my code:

```
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Net;
using namespace System::Windows;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hinstDLL,_In_ DWORD     fdwReason,_In_ LPVOID    lpvReserved)
{
    if (fdwReason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH) {
        System::Windows::Forms::MessageBox::Show("test");
        WebClient web;
        String^ Data = web.DownloadString("http://www.google.com");
        System::Windows::Forms::MessageBox::Show(Data);
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

It works properly until the Data string is initialized, for some reason the execution stops there. MessageBox::Show("test"); Works though, but nothing after that.
What could be causing this?

Comment: Calling into managed code from DllMain is very unsupported. Many many things can/are going wrong.

Comment: @LoganCapaldo I totally agree, but I'd know the specific reason why **this** fails.

Comment: You assume that WebClient can do its job without needing any DLLs.  Idle hope it turns out, a fair miracle that you have the CLR and the jitter available in the first place and that they are the right version.  But luck ran out at Winsocks (aka ws2_32.dll).  Plus the typical large amount of shrink-wrapped malware that is dragged in as well.  You'll need CreateThread to get somewhere.  And lots of luck.

Comment: @HansPassant It was about the ws2_32.lib! I linked the dll against that and now it actually works. Can you add your comment as a solution so I can upvote it & choose it as an answer so other people that run into same problem can see it! :)

Comment: Awgodno, I don't want to hear from the next hundred programmers without luck.  Or from you when you run this on another machine with a different anti-malware product for that matter.  Just post the answer yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you just have to link your managed/native mixed dll against winsock libraries (ws2_32.lib) & create a separate thread for the download.